# PHP undefined index error when clicking a url and invoking a php script

Tags: php

I have a call to a PHP script from my home page which I do like this:

```
echo '<a href="/problems/delete_problem.php?problem_id='.$problem_id.'">Delete</a>';
```

So it is pretty standard.

Then in my PHP I have this code:

```
<?php
// delete_problem

include '../connect.php'; // Here I have db connection settings

error_log ( ".......in delete problem");

$problem_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["problem_id"]);

?>
```

And the last line where I try to get the problem_id is throwing the undefined index error. Any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show an example value for `problem_id`. Does it get set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you got an actual connection inside connect.php? Or does it just store variables and the like?

`mysql_real_escape_string` may be causing a problem as if a connection is not available it will fail.

Beyond that, try echoing out the contents of the GET variable. You can also check whether it exists by using `(isset($_GET["problem_id"]))`.

Comment: Thats what I thought about the mysql_real_escape_string but there is an actual connection..which makes this error strange to me.

Comment: Try echoing out the variable and making sure it exists, as above - that will help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: Why would you want to do a mysql_real_escape string on a variable that will serve as an integer?

Comment: Haha, true. You could settype or cast to int instead, or is_numeric.

Answer (score 2):

For values coming from the user, always make sure they are present and possibly validate their format.

Use:

```
if (isset($_GET['problem_id']) && trim($_GET['problem_id']) != '') {
    $problem_id = $_GET['problem_id'];
    // make sure it is a number
} else {
   echo "No problem id given!";
}
```

That warning appears because the $_GET array doesn't contain a value problem_id, most likely because it was not passed with the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Bleh, all you people with the mysql_real_escape string...

Always check if a variable is set before you try and assign the value of it to another variable.

**Also use (int) to cast!!**

```
if (isset($_GET["problem_id"])){
  $problem_id = (int) $_GET["problem_id"];
}
```